# Redirect Dynamic URL with questionmark and ampersand?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have redirect dynamic URL's which I'd like to redirect (301).

Link type 1
**OLD -** /?mainPage=Contact
**NEW -** /Contact

Link type 2
**OLD -** /?mainPage=Shows&show=circus
**NEW -** /shows/circus

How to do this?

Comment: rewriterule /?mainPage=Contact$
/Contact
[R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroTouzón, but this doesn't seem to work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that URL, you can use the following rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?mainPage=$1&show=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

To redirect a URL using a query:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mainPage=Optredens&show=petitcirque$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /shows/le-petit-cirque/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How do I fix this with this URL's?  
**OLD** /?mainPage=Optredens&show=petitcirque  
**NEW** /shows/le-petit-cirque

Comment: If you want to redirect old URLs to new ones, then you need to use `Redirect 301`.

Comment: That wouldn't work for url's with '?' and '&' in it, am I right. Quite new to this.

Comment: Yes correct, you would need to use `{QUERY_STRING}` in order to do this. See my edit for an example.